# How to use tr in pipeline?

Tags: pipe, tr

Input file:

```
ID_REF,GSM2819484,GSM2819485,GSM2819486,GSM2819487,GSM2819488,GSM2819489,GSM2819490,GSM2819491,GSM2819492,GSM2819493
```

My code:

```
awk -F, '{$1="";print substr($0,2)}’  | tr  ' ' '\n' > result
```

tr is the one giving the issue. How can I use tr in a pipeline?

Expected output:

```
GSM2819484
GSM2819485
GSM2819486
GSM2819487
GSM2819488
GSM2819489
GSM2819490
GSM2819491
GSM2819492
GSM2819493
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks simpler to just use `tr` from the get go and then filter the first line using `tail` like this:

```bash
echo "ID_REF,GSM2819484,GSM2819485,GSM2819486,GSM2819487,GSM2819488,GSM2819489,GSM2819490,GSM2819491,GSM2819492,GSM2819493" | tr ',' '\n' | tail -n+2
```

But as far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with your command except the `’` at the end of the awk command should be an `'`.

```bash
awk -F, '{$1="";print substr($0,2)}’  | tr  ' ' '\n' > result
                                   ^ this should be '
```

With the correct character there your command also works for me!

Comment: Thanks! I feel so stupid. I just copied and pasted this command from Notion, so it's likely that's the reason it got messed up :(

Comment: Thanks also for the improvement to my code :D